# Are the vectors of a $\lambda$-string for an endomorphism linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Definition ($\lambda$-string).** Let $\mathbb{V}$ be a vector space over an algebric field $\mathbb{K}$, let $f \colon \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V} $ be an endomorphism and let $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$. 
A set $S=\{u_1, u_2, \dots, u_p\}$ of $p$ vectors belonging to $\mathbb{V}$ is called $\lambda$-string  of $p$ length for $f$ if this two conditions hold:

1.
$$u_1 \neq 0\,,$$

2.
\begin{cases} f(u_p) = \lambda u_p + u_{p-1}\,,\\[8pt] f(u_{p-1}) = \lambda u_{p-1} + u_{p-2}\,,\\[8pt]  \dots \\[8pt] f(u_1)=\lambda u_1\,.\end{cases}

---

I want to prove that S is linearly independent.


I know that a sequence of vectors from a vector space is linear independent if their linear combination returns null vector only when all the scalar coefficients in the combination are equal to zero (I mean the neutral element in $\mathbb{K}$). 

My idea is demonstrate the following implication:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{\sum_{i=1}^{p}{\alpha_iu_i}=0 \implies \alpha_i=0 \quad\forall i \in \{1,2,\dots,p\}\,.}
$$

Here is my reasoning:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{p}{\alpha_iu_i}=0 \implies f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{p}{\alpha_iu_i}\right)=0 \implies \sum_{i=1}^{p}{\alpha_if(u_i)}=0\implies \alpha_1f(u_1)+\sum_{i=2}^{p}{\alpha_if(u_i)}=0\,,$$
by the definition of $\lambda$-string $f(u_1)=\lambda u_1$ and $f(u_i)=\lambda u_i + u_{i-1}$ for $2 \le i \le p$, so we obtain:

$$
\alpha_1\lambda u_1+\sum_{i=2}^{p}{\alpha_i(\lambda u_i+u_{i-1})}=0\implies
\lambda\left(\alpha_1 u_1+\sum_{i=2}^{p}{\alpha_iu_i}\right)+\sum_{i=2}^{p}{\alpha_iu_{i-1}}=0 \implies
$$

$$
\lambda\sum_{i=1}^{p}{\alpha_iu_i}+\sum_{i=2}^{p}{\alpha_iu_{i-1}}=0\,,
$$
since the first summatory is null, this means that:
$$
\sum_{i=2}^{p}{\alpha_iu_{i-1}}=0\,. \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
At this point I write the last identity in this way:
$$
\alpha_2 u_1+\sum_{i=3}^{p}{\alpha_iu_{i-1}}=0
$$
and apply the endomorphism:
$$
\alpha_2 \lambda u_1 + \sum_{i=3}^{p}{\alpha_i(\lambda u_{i-1}+u_{i-2})}=0 \implies \lambda \left(\alpha_2 u_1+\sum_{i=3}^{p}{\alpha_iu_{i-1}}\right)+\sum_{i=3}^{p}{\alpha_iu_{i-2}}=0 \implies
$$
$$
\lambda\sum_{i=2}^{p}{\alpha_i u_{i-1}}+\sum_{i=3}^{p}{\alpha_i u_{i-2}}=0\,,
$$
but \eqref{1} says us that the first summatory in the previous identity is null, for this reason:
$$
\sum_{i=3}^{p}{\alpha_i u_{i-2}}=0\,. \tag{2}\label{2}
$$
Iterating the procedure we could write this system of identies:
$$
\begin{cases} \sum_{i=1}^{p}{\alpha_i u_{i}}=0\,, \\[15pt] \sum_{i=2}^{p}{\alpha_i u_{i-1}}=0\,, \\[15pt] \sum_{i=3}^{p}{\alpha_i u_{i-2}}=0 \,,\\[15pt] \sum_{i=4}^{p}{\alpha_i u_{i-3}}=0 \,,\\[15pt] \dots \\[15pt] \sum_{i=k}^{p}{\alpha_i u_{i-k+1}}=0\,, \\[15pt] \dots \\[15pt] \alpha_{p-2}u_1+\alpha_{p-1}u_2+\alpha_p u_3=0\,,\\[15pt]\alpha_{p-1}u_1+\alpha_p u_2=0\,,\\[15pt] \alpha_p u_1=0\,,\end{cases}
\tag{3}\label{3}
$$
where the last equation show us that $\alpha_p=0$ necessarily because $u_1 \neq 0$, but this means also $\alpha_{p-1}=0$ that implies $\alpha_{p-2}=0$. At the end we can deduce that $\alpha_i=0 \quad \forall i\in\{1,2,\dots,p\}$.

---

I'm having difficulty proving that $S$ is linearly independent. Could someone tell me if my reasoning is correct? 

I would like to specify that proving the linear indipendence of the vectors of a $\lambda$-string is an exercise proposed by my professor of geometry some months ago.


Thanks in advance for your attention and help.